# `.explain()` on a query from profiler

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**TL;DR: Is there maybe a native way to run .explain() on a query from profiler by either passing whole profiler result or just the query part?**

Query

```
db.test.find({ "name": "Ale" })
```

After running this query we can retrieve [system.profile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#view-profiler-data) for it which looks like this:

```
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "test.test",
    "query" : {
        "find" : "test",
        "filter" : {
            "name" : "Ale"
        }
    },
    "keysExamined" : 0,
    "docsExamined" : 27,
    "cursorExhausted" : true,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "locks" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(2)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        }
    },
    "nreturned" : 1,
    "responseLength" : 149,
    "protocol" : "op_command",
    "millis" : 12,
    "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN",
    "execStats" : {
        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
        "filter" : {
            "name" : {
                "$eq" : "Ale"
            }
        },
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
        "works" : 29,
        "advanced" : 1,
        "needTime" : 27,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 0,
        "restoreState" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "direction" : "forward",
        "docsExamined" : 27
    },
    "ts" : ISODate("2017-03-28T12:00:29.582Z"),
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "appName" : "MongoDB Shell",
    "allUsers" : [ ],
    "user" : ""
}
```

Now, I would like to run [.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) on the query from profiler. I don't have access to the original query, only to the profiler and so to the query in profiler which looks like this (after extracting it from profiler output above):

```
"op" : "query",
"ns" : "test.test",
"query" : {
    "find" : "test",
    "filter" : {
        "name" : "Ale"
    }
}
```

To be able to run [.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) on this query I would need to convert it back to the form:

```
db.test.find({ "name": "Ale" })
```

and append [.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) to it:

```
db.test.find({ "name": "Ale" }).explain()
```

This is a bit problematic as you can have different query types - not only `find()` but also `aggregate()`, `count()`, `distinct()`, `group()`, `remove()` and `update()`.

Is there maybe a native way to run [.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) on a query from profiler by either passing whole profiler result or just the query part?

Comment: db.<collectionName>.explain() gives you explainable cursor. Now you can run find/count/group etc operations on this explainable object. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `query` value is in [db.runCommand()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/) format, so you can repeat it as:

```
db.runCommand({
    "find" : "test",
    "filter" : {
        "name" : "Ale"
    }
})
```

or

```
var query = db.system.profile.findOne({...}).query;
db.runCommand(query);
```

To explain this query, you can use it in [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/explain) command:

```
db.runCommand({
    explain: {
        "find" : "test",
        "filter" : {
            "name" : "Ale"
        }
    }
})
```

or

```
var query = db.system.profile.findOne({...}).query;
db.runCommand({explain: query});
```

**EDIT:**

An example for `update` command requires a bit of re-shaping:

```
var update = (({ ns, query, updateobj }) => ({ 
    update: ns.split(/\./).slice(1).join('.'), // collection name
    updates:[{q:query, u:updateobj}] // filter and update
}))(db.system.profile.findOne({"op" : "update", ... }));
db.runCommand({explain: update});
```

Comment: Simply genius! Thanks!

Comment: This looked promising but it turns out it's not so easy: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/mongodb-user/jSuSIqz4I9Q/VsCauRI3BAAJ

Comment: It is even more complex than described there. There is no such thing as explain from geoNear, getMore, insert, etc. The list of explainable commands is documented there: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/explain/#dbcmd.explain. I have updated the answer with an example for update command, and the others can do the same.